# Downloading a file using extjs+spring

Tags: hibernate, extjs, spring-mvc, download

My application uses ExtJs as front end ans Spring MVC+Hibernate JPA as backend. I need to download a file. The url of the document is retrieved using the AJAX request.there is a Download button, and when the user clicks it, there should be an option for Save As.

```
   var body = Ext.getBody();
    var form = body.createChild({
    tag:'form'
   ,cls:'x-hidden'
   ,id:'form'
   ,action:'document/download/'+selDocument.data.documentId
   ,target:'iframe'

       });
    form.dom.submit();
```

This code is working fine for me now. The only problem is that the page gets refreshed when I click download. Is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the quickest way of doing that would be to spawn a new window with the URL of the download as the target..

`window.open(url);`

The browser will open a new window, show the download dialog control and then close the window.

Comment: you meant to say there is nothing to be done in the server side? No reading of the file required? If i'm using simply the document path to start download, that document should have been saved somewhere in application server no?

Comment: The question was "The only problem is that the page gets refreshed when I click download. Is there any way to avoid that?", the answer is to open the url in a new window so it doesn't redirect your current page